# pig order by with rank and join the rank together

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following data with the schema (t0:chararray, t1:int)

```
a0 1
a1 7
b2 9
a2 4
b0 6
```

And I want to order it `t1` and then combine with a rank

```
a0 1 1
a2 4 2
b0 6 3
a1 7 4
b2 9 5
```

Is there any convenient way without writing UDF in pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the RANK operation in Pig. This should be sufficient:

```
X = rank A by t1 ASC;
```

Please see the [Pig docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#rank) for more details.